# How to import data from a .sql file to a particular database of mysql

Tags: mysql

To import data into a table,we use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

But i want to import data from a .sql file into a database specifying its name
how to do this

Answer (score 0):

In SQL:

```
use dbname;
source data.sql;
```

In Linux:

```
shell> mysql dbname < data.sql
```

You might need to use full path to file.

Comment: No problem. Confirm correct answer so everyone can see it :)